# Uknown increment id from table [LINQ-ASP.NET-EF]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a database table that is called reaction. This table has the following fields:

-id (int-PK-NotNull) (auto increment)
-content (string-NotNull)
-date (date-NotNUll)

When I want to add a row to the database I use the following code:

```
        REACTION reaction = new REACTION
        {
            content = "blablabla",
            date = DateTime.Now

        };

        db.REACTIONs.InsertOnSubmit(reaction);


        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Now, when I check the database the field has been added and has an id (example 15). But how do I "get" the id when I don't know it in the database. I want the id of the row that I just made an object of without peaking into the database. But I have absolutely no idea on how to do this. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `db.SubtmitChanges()` the ID of the object should be populated

**EDIT**

Just to make it completely clear what happens:

```
REACTION reaction = new REACTION
{
    content = "blablabla",
    date = DateTime.Now
};

// At this point reaction.ID == 0 or null

db.REACTIONs.InsertOnSubmit(reaction);


db.SubmitChanges();

var id = reaction.ID; // Now ID will have the value that was generated when the row was inserted
```

Comment: I know it does that, but I don't know what that id is. One way to see what id was given is looking it up in the database, however, I want the other way and want to retrieve that id so I can make my program dynamic.

Comment: Not sure I follow you... your reaction.ID will now contain the ID you want. Why can't you use that?

Comment: That's what Ben's saying.

reaction.ID after the savechanges *should* contain the ID it inserted.

Comment: Okay but how do I know what it inserted?